# Count Up Date Timer Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, timer, counter, leap-year

i was wondering How to get this Time Format.. I want a Count Up Timer on Date Like this one on the Link..

Any Answers or Suggestions will be appreciated. Thank You, Looking Forward to you replies.

[I want it to be Like This.](http://www.tickcounter.com/countup/1213502400000/asia-shanghai/ydhms/FFFFFF3B5998000000FF0000/)

[Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/redang3l/2f30178y/)

```
$(function(){
var calcNewYear = setInterval(function(){
    date_started = new Date("June 15, 2008");
    date_now = new Date();'

    seconds = Math.floor((date_now - (date_started))/1000);
    minutes = Math.floor(seconds/60);
    hours = Math.floor(minutes/60);
    days = Math.floor(hours/24);
    years = Math.floor(days/365);


    days = days -(years*365);
    hours = hours-(years*365*24)-(days*24);
    minutes = minutes-(years*365*24*60)-(days*24*60)-(hours*60);
    seconds = seconds-(years*365*24*60*60)-(days*24*60*60)-(hours*60*60)-(minutes*60);

    $("#mission").text( years + "Years |" + days + "Days |" + hours + "Hours |" + seconds + "Seconds");
},1000);
```

});

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far, so that you can get help and suggestions.

Comment: Hello, thanks for responding..I want to include the Leap Year on my code because without that the date won't be exact. Heres what i've done so far [link](https://jsfiddle.net/redang3l/2f30178y/)

But i want to be like the timer here [Link](http://www.tickcounter.com/countup/1213502400000/asia-shanghai/ydhms/FFFFFF3B5998000000FF0000/)

Comment: Add the fiddle link in your question.

Answer (score 0):

For Leap Year- Use modulus option to check whether it is multiple of four and then using if condition and changing 365 days to 366  JsFiddle for reference-https://jsfiddle.net/Nagasai_Aytha/2f30178y/2/

```
          if (years % 4 == 0) {
          days = days - (years * 366);
          hours = hours - (years * 366 * 24) - (days * 24);
          minutes = minutes - (years * 366 * 24 * 60) - (days * 24 * 60) - (hours * 60);
          seconds = seconds - (years * 366 * 24 * 60 * 60) - (days * 24 * 60 * 60) - (hours * 60 * 60) - (minutes * 60);

      } else {


          days = days - (years * 365);
          hours = hours - (years * 365 * 24) - (days * 24);
          minutes = minutes - (years * 365 * 24 * 60) - (days * 24 * 60) - (hours * 60);
          seconds = seconds - (years * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60) - (days * 24 * 60 * 60) - (hours * 60 * 60) - (minutes * 60);
      }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply... But i guess it won't work, because we declare  the `years = Math.floor(days/365);` Thank you for helping me to find an answer..

Comment: Yes..for leap year I have used 366 ..and during leap year it used 366 instead if 365. Did my answer help your question.If so can you mark it answered :)

Comment: Actually its not XD hehe, this is the correct format that i aimed for.. [This](http://www.tickcounter.com/countup/1213502400000/asia-shanghai/ydhms/FFFFFF3B5998000000FF0000/).. but i really appreciate your reply to my post, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this code. Hope it will help others with the same problem i had.

```
$(function(){
var calcNewYear = setInterval(function(){
    date_started = new Date("June 15, 2008");
    date_now = new Date();
    one_day=1000*60*60*24;
    seconds = Math.floor((date_now - (date_started))/1000);
    minutes = Math.floor(seconds/60);
    hours = Math.floor(minutes/60);
    days = Math.floor((date_now - (date_started))/one_day); ///(hour/24);
    years = Math.floor(days / 365.25);
    day1= Math.floor(days % 365.25);


    // days = days -(years*365);
    hours = hours-(days*24); //(years*365*24)-(days*24);
    minutes = minutes-(days*24*60)-(hours*60); //minutes-(years*365*24*60)-(days*24*60)-(hours*60);
    seconds = seconds-(days*24*60*60)-(hours*60*60)-(minutes*60); //seconds-(years*365*24*60*60)-(days*24*60*60)-(hours*60*60)-(minutes*60);

    $("#mission").text( years + "Years |" + day1 + "Days |" + hours + "Hours |" + seconds + "Seconds");
},1000);
});
```